# OnTerminate() method is not called when Execute() terminates in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am using a **TThread** to populate an **SQL** database.
When this thread ends, is must enable some objects on the main form.

I want this code to be inside the `OnTerminate()` event.

However when the `Execute()` method ends, `OnTerminate()` is not called.

Why is this not called?
Am I missing or forgetting something?

This is the code in the main form:

```
void __fastcall TAF_Calc_Form::Button_LUClick(TObject *Sender)
{
Button_LU->Enabled = false;

TUrenThread* ut = new TUrenThread(true); 
ut->FreeOnTerminate = true;
ut->Start();
}
```

This is the `Execute()` code:

```
void __fastcall TUrenThread::Execute()
{

    Synchronize(&MoveFirst_AD);

    while (!AF_Calc_Form->PvQ_AfleverD->Eof)
    {

           //code executes here
    };
}
```

This is the `OnTerminate()` method:

```
void __fastcall TUrenThread::OnTerminate()
{
    AF_Calc_Form->Button_LU->Enabled = false;

}
```

Comment: Not sure with Builder.  Does the declaration of TUrenThread::OnTerminate need an override directive, (and does it have one)?

Answer (score 0):

`TThread` does not have an `OnTerminate()` **method**.  It has a `DoTerminate()` **virtual method** that triggers an `OnTerminate` **event handler**.  You are not assigning a handler to the `OnTerminate` event, or overriding the `DoTerminate()` method.  That is why your code is not being called.

Try this instead:

```
void __fastcall TAF_Calc_Form::Button_LUClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    Button_LU->Enabled = false;

    TUrenThread* ut = new TUrenThread(true); 
    ut->FreeOnTerminate = true;
    ut->OnTerminate = &UrenThreadTerminated; // <-- add this
    ut->Start();
}

void __fastcall TAF_Calc_Form::UrenThreadTerminated(TObject *Sender)
{
    // shouldn't this be assigning true instead of false?
    Button_LU->Enabled = false;
}
```